# when I press the folder in Unity it only shows the folders in it or the documents in it can someone help me?? #Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

Normally in Unity when you press a file shows you the files images when I press the folder it only shows the folders in it or the documents in it can someone help me?Mine is like this:
[image]

It is important. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=on9nwbZngyw&t=511s this is the video I am watching I need tips or solutions

Comment: Reset your window layout

Comment: I don't understand/see the issue .. what exactly is the question?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the "Project" tab at the top of the window.  Set it to "One Column Layout" instead of "Two Column Layout."

Comment: Thanks I really needed it.